# Match something before a set of characters and until a character in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently struggling with finding a way to extract domain names in urls.

My strings

```
xyz.weam.com 
we2.wal.com 
abc.workwork.google.net
```

I would like it to look for (com|org|net) and take the string before the match including the match until it hits the first (`.`) going backwards.

I have tried different combinations of lookbehind and positive lookahead but I was never able to make it stop at the right dot (`.`).

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: If positive lookbehinds are available then this would work `(?<=\.)[^.]+?(?=\.(?:com|org|net)$)`

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Thanks, it used JavaScript and your query didn't work.

Comment: It's usually just as simple and more performant to use capturing groups instead of lookarounds, e.g. `\.([^.]+).(?:com|net|org)$` and extract your target value from the first capturing group (`"abc.workwork.google.net".match(/\.([^.]+).(?:com|net|org)$/)[1]`)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that did the trick. I'm wondering though if it is possible to  make it generic to capture any TLD that could be thrown there rather than specifying them in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys and especially to **Aaron**, his answer worked perfectly.

His Regex did the trick.

```
\.([^.]+).(?:com|net|org)$
```

Comment: `[^.]+\.(?:com|net|org)$`